# Theano indexing details

Tags: python, theano

I'm following Theano tutorial (particularly http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html) and I'm trying to understand this "self evident" code:

```
    # y.shape[0] is (symbolically) the number of rows in y, i.e.,
    # number of examples (call it n) in the minibatch
    # T.arange(y.shape[0]) is a symbolic vector which will contain
    # [0,1,2,... n-1] T.log(self.p_y_given_x) is a matrix of
    # Log-Probabilities (call it LP) with one row per example and
    # one column per class LP[T.arange(y.shape[0]),y] is a vector
    # v containing [LP[0,y[0]], LP[1,y[1]], LP[2,y[2]], ...,
    # LP[n-1,y[n-1]]] and T.mean(LP[T.arange(y.shape[0]),y]) is
    # the mean (across minibatch examples) of the elements in v,
    # i.e., the mean log-likelihood across the minibatch.

    return -T.mean(T.log(self.p_y_given_x)[T.arange(y.shape[0]), y])
```

My questions are:

1. what is the [T.arange(y.shape[0]), y] after the function call?
2. How does it return [LP[0,y[0]], LP[1,y[1]], LP[2,y[2]], ..., LP[n-1,y[n-1]]]
3. How does T.mean know how to compute the mean over something like that (whatever it is)?
4. Could you please generalize concepts I don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer (NLL stands for negative log likelihood):

NLL is a symbolic variable ; to get the actual value of NLL, this symbolic
expression has to be compiled into a Theano function (see the Theano
tutorial for more details)
`NLL = -T.sum(T.log(p_y_given_x)[T.arange(y.shape[0]), y])`
note on syntax: `T.arange(y.shape[0])` is a vector of integers `[0,1,2,...,len(y)]`.
Indexing a matrix M by the two vectors `[0,1,...,K], [a,b,...,k]` returns the
elements `M[0,a], M[1,b], ..., M[K,k]` as a vector.  Here, we use this
syntax to retrieve the log-probability of the correct labels, y.